# Minimum boolean lattice containing all poset of fixed size

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I need help with the following:

What is the minimum $n$ such that the boolean lattice $2^{[n]}$ contains all posets of size $m$?

I noticed that it should contain a chain of length $m$, and the longest chain in $2^{[n]}$ has length $n+1$, so $n \ge m - 1$.

Also it should contain an antichain of size $m$, so $n \geq n'$, where $n'$ is the least number such that ${n' \choose \lfloor n'/2\rfloor} \geq m$. By manually checking we can see that for $m = 1,2,3,4$; $n$ is respectively $0,2,3,4$, and from there the first condition starts to imply the second, and my conjecture is that if $m \geq 5$ then $n = m-1$.

I appreciate any help trying to prove (or disprove) this. Thanks.

Comment: What is $[n]$? The ordinal corresponding to $n$?

Comment: @dfeuer: $[n]$ is a fairly standard notation for $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** map each element of the poset to its down-set.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a bit more? Is the idea to construct all the posets from the downsets?

Comment: @MikeSB, the point is that any poset can be embedded into the lattice of subsets of its underlying set in two natural ways. One maps each element to its down-set: $x\mapsto\{y\in S:y\le x\}$. The other maps each element to its up-set: $x\mapsto\{y\in S:y\ge x\}$. The down-set approach is the embedding, $\le$ to $\subseteq$; the up-set gives the dual embedding, $\le$ to $\supseteq$. There are, of course, two natural correspondences between $\mathcal P(S)$ and $2^S$ for any set $S$.

Comment: I see, so that gives me and embedding of any $m$ element poset into $2^{[m]}$, so we get $m-1 \leq n \leq m$, but how do I decide which of the two values is the answer?

Comment: @MikeSB, I think the trouble is at the bottom. There's only one empty set, but you need to distinguish different chains with different least elements. That is, it's natural to *try* to match elements to their *strict* down-sets, but it doesn't quite work. I believe the answer is $n=m$ with the special exception of $m=1$.

Comment: You can easily check manually for, say, $m=3$. There aren't that many three-element posets.